# TVirtualStringTree, position of the tree structure

Tags: delphi, tvirtualstringtree

The visual tree structure of the VirtualStringTree always sticks to the 1st column (the one with index = 0). When you change columns sequence by dragging a column header the tree may look weird (the image below). Is it possible to have the structure be seen always in the first visible column?
[image: Test]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure is displayed based on the `TVirtualStringTree.Header.MainColumn` which needs to be changed every time a column is moved, because moving a column doesn't change its index, but the `TVirtualTreeColumn.Position` property. The easiest way is to use `OnHeaderDragged`.

```
procedure HeaderDragged(Sender: TVTHeader; Column: TColumnIndex; OldPosition: Integer);
begin
  MyTree.Header.MainColumn := MyTree.Header.Columns.ColumnFromPosition(0);
end;
```